# Define article id

Tags: php

I have a page of a separate article to which we go by slug

**php.blade**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')

    <div class="article-wrapper">
        <div class="container">
            <h1>{{ $article->title }}</h1>
            <h3>{{ $article->subtitle }}</h3>
            <img src="{{ $article->main_image }}" alt="">
            <h3>{{ date('d F Y', strtotime($article->published_at)) }}</h3>
            <h3>{{ $article->views }} Views</h3>

            @foreach($article_blocks as $article_block)
            <div class="text-image">
                <h2>{{ $article_block->title_1 }}</h2>
                <h3>{{ $article_block->text_1 }}</h3>
                <img src="{{ $article_block->main_image }}" alt="">
            </div>
            @endforeach
@endsection
```

**controller**

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $article = Article::where('slug', $slug)->first();

        $article_blocks = ArticleBlock::where('article_id', 1)->get();

        return view('article', compact('article', 'article_blocks'));
    }
```

Next, I have another model for blocks, each article has its own blocks, as you can see in my controller, I manually write the article ID to get the blocks specific for it.

How to make it itself determine which article we are on, and display blocks only for it?

Comment: `$article->id` obviously.

Comment: But I presume with correct relations between Article and ArticleBlock, single query will return Article with blocks, something like `article->blocks`.

Comment: this will not work `$article_blocks = ArticleBlock::where($article->id)->get();`

Comment: `ArticleBlock::where('article_id', $article->id)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try :

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
    {
        $article = Article::firstWhere('slug', $slug);

        $article_blocks = ArticleBlock::where('article_id', $article->id)->get();

        return view('article', compact('article', 'article_blocks'));
    }
```

If you have created relationships between your models, you can use it as follows:

```
public function index(Request $request, $slug)
        {
            $article = Article::with('articleBlock')->where('slug', $slug)->get();
    
            return view('article', compact('article'));
        }
```

Comment: thanks, I will take into account ))